# 2017 MacBook Pro normal idle temperatures and fan speeds?

Tags: temperature

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro that feels somewhat warm to touch, even when there is little load on the CPU.  Even when the CPU is ~95% idle (according to Activity Monitor), Macs Fan Control is reporting temperatures around 55-60°C.  Is this normal behavior?

When I temporarily adjust the fan speed to a high RPM, the fans can clearly be heard running.  But for some reason, the fans don't seem to kick in above the ~2000 RPM minimum even when the temperature rises, to 67°C for example.

Is this normal, or is there something that I can do to correct this?

Comment: I don't know about the Mac laptops but my older iMac has a temperature on the power supply heatsink of 81˚C. You should get the app Temperature Gauge from the app store (it is free) because it shows you the temperature at various places on your computer. You can determine where the 67˚C comes from and that may help you determine if it is ok.